# Replacing @*@ environment variable tokens with their current values, _within files_

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix

I would like to know what shell command would allow me to replace the tokens `e.g. myproperty='@SOME_ENV_VARIABLE@'` defined in a file with their corresponding environment variables in unix.

i.e.

```
cat FILE1 ;
someproperty='@SOME_ENV_VARIABLE@'

export SOME_ENV_VARIABLE=twochain;
...do the replace here with FILE1...

cat FILE1 ;
someproperty='twochain'
```

Comment: I would use the `awk` command for that.

Comment: @thenaglecode your question is unclear, please rephrase it.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1610500/171318 It is using sed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
perl -pe 's/\@(.*?)\@/$ENV{$1}/g' < infile > outfile
```

**EDIT:**
To modify a particular file in-place, creating a backup of the original in `somefile.bak`:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/\@(.*?)\@/$ENV{$1}/g' somefile
```

Delete the `.bak` characters to avoid creating any backup file.

Comment: i would add `[^\s]*?` inside the @ signs to not catch whitespace

Answer (score 0):

Using sed

```
export SOME_ENV_VARIABLE=twochain;
sed -i "s/@[^@]*@/${SOME_ENV_VARIABLE}/" FILE1
```

Comment: what part did you think it is not answer? did you know sed?